# mysqldump batch script runs but leaves empty file

Tags: batch-file, mysql

I have made a simple batch script to back up a database, however when it runs it creates a empty file. This batch script is located in the same folder where mysqldump.exe is located. Following  code:

```
@ECHO off
start /wait mysqldump.exe -u user -p "password" database > "Z:\sql-backup\"database-backup.sql
```

Any help would really help. New to Batch scripting.

Comment: Remove the double quotes in the destination

Comment: Nope, same, it runs, but the file is empty.

Comment: remove the start /wait.. at least temporarily and maybe you will see an error message.

Comment: Also quotes from your password

Comment: Removing the start /wait fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had used the below commands in batch file and it has worked properly.
First of all you should goto bin directory and issue the below mentioned mysqldump command. The same you can mention in the batch file as it is.

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

mysqldump -uroot -ppassword database >  "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data\"Database_bkp.sql